# Assign individual network ports on same adapter with ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Can I assign individual ports on a single adapter to different vSwitches? In other words can I assign 2 ports for SAN and 2 ports for LAN on a 4 port nic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Each port can be assigned via the adapter dialog in the vSwitch configuration screen. This is a standard task...

Here's an example with a 4-port Intel card:

In the "Network Adapters" configuration page, the four vmnicX devices show up with their link and speed status.

[image]

---

In the vSwitch configuration, the "Physical Adapters" shows which vmnics are assigned to which switch. I don't have any assigned to the storage network defined below, but I could easily add one.

[image]

---

In the vSwitch properties page, you can add adapters listed as "unclaimed adapters" to a particular vSwitch. In your case, add two to your Virtual Machine network vSwitch and add two to your storage vSwitch.

[image]

Comment: It appears as one nic. I can't seem to add each port to a different vSwitch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the edits with examples.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that my motherboard has independent chipsets for each port. For some reason each is different, and one of them isn't supported by ESXi out of the box.